# Let $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb {R}$ be a $C^1$-function with $D_2f(0,0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What's true and what's false?

1. Let $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb {R}$ be a $C^1$-function with $D_2f(0,0)=1$. Assume $g:\mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {R}$ fulfills $g(x)=0$ and $f(x,g(x))=0$, then $g$ is in a neighbourhood of $0$ continuous differentiable.
2. For every function $g:\mathbb {R}^m \to \mathbb {R}^n$ exists a function $f:\mathbb {R}^{m+n} \to \mathbb {R}^n$ such that $(x,g(x))$ exactly describes the solution $f(x,y)=0$

---

I'm pretty sure that 1. is true, that's just the implicit function theorem. But I don't really know about 2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $g$, let $f(x,y)=y-g(x).$ Then $$(x,y)~{\rm satisfies ~}f(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow y=g(x),~{\rm i.e.~}(x,y)=(x,g(x)).$$ In other words, the zero set of $f(x,y)$ represents $\Gamma_g=\{(x,y)~|~y=g(x)\},$ namely the graph of $g$.